# Client app to view React native Realm database?

Tags: react-native, realm

Is there any applications like Navicat(sadly it supports SQLite) that help viewing realm database which is used in react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm provides the MongoDB Realm Studio app on multiple platforms that allows the developer to interact with a LOCAL Realm Database

Here's a link [MongoDB Realm Studio](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/studio/)

You can also run basic queries and explore other aspects of your data.

If you want to interact with a SYNC'd database, you will need to log into the MongoDB Realm Console website.